# Validate select2 tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have the following simple code to validate user input:

```
$('#band_info :input').each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {               
        $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
    } 
});
```

This works. But when It comes to the select2 form:

```
<select class="form-control genreOptions" id="Genre" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

It don't work quite well. After I have inserted a tag, It still prints a red border. This because after I have inserted a tag, a empty input-field Is inserted. You can see a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8bg2y0q3/1/

Try to add a tag, and then inspect the field. How can I ignore this empty input field that is generated after I have chosen a tag?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki: What do u mean?

Comment: _After I have inserted a tag, It still prints a red border._ i can't see any red border and no validation function in your fiddle.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki: That fiddles Is not mine. I use the same code there. I want to igonre the input-field that Is generated after you have added a tag.

Comment: So please try to add a fiddle that represent your situation, so we could check it.